# Periodic Shifting Lock

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, password

I'm a delivery agent for UPS. On the package, I've been given instructions to drop off the package at a mail reception building accessible only through a "Periodic Shifting Lock," which I assume means that the password will change periodically. I've been given today's password, which is `Scrutiny`. On the keypad, however, there are only numbers! I've got to get in before it changes, I don't have another code.

Hint 1:

> I need to think positive

Hint 2:

> It is a 9-digit password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Guess is

> 22 45 23 8 40

Because

> Sc Ru Ti N Y are all elements on the periodic table (Atomic numbers 21, 44, 22, 7, 39) 
>  shift everything over one to make it one higher

Comment: Nice job! You have mastered the Scrutinizing shift. Do you think I should make a sequel?

Comment: @CStafford-14 I thought it was quite clever, I'm sure a sequel would be as well :)